# Windows xcopy 0 File(s) copied

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I am trying to copy a directory but get the following:

```
xcopy ..\node_modules\ \node_modules\
```

> 0 File(s) copied

I run as administrator, but still get the error. Any ideas please?

p.s I actually use the following to stipulate it's a directory. But the above also fails:

```
echo d | xcopy /d /y ..\node_modules\ \node_modules\
```

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps there is nothing (no files) to copy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `xcopy /E` flag to copy the entire directory and subdirectories. Also remove the starting \ of the destination. The trailing slash should prevent the file or directory prompt.

```
xcopy /E ..\node_modules node_modules\
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but whe I try what you say, I get `Invalid path
0 File(s) copied`

Comment: My apologies, try again without the source back slash

Comment: is it only windows that makes scripting difficult :). THanks for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
xcopy ..\node_modules\* \node_modules\
```

You are specifying the source directory, but not which files to copy.

Comment: Thanks fro your reply, but when I try what you suggest, I get: `0 File(s) copied`

Answer (score 0):

To copy all the contents like folder, sub-folder or chain of folders we can use below command:

`xcopy file-to-copy-path\ where-to-copy-path\ /s /i`

`/s`    copies folders and sub-folders

`/i`   If in doubt always assume the destination is a folder e.g. when the destination does not exist.